AWS Application Logs: Cost Effective Storage + Reliable near real-time access
Looking for the most cost-effective way to store and access Lambda logs in real near-time, or a comparison of such methods.  Account for all associated cost.
My end goal is to have a raw, simple, non-interactive webpage showing all application logs. Elastic is an overkill for my purpose.
Random examples:

Lambda -> Cloudwatch. As needed, read Cloudwatch logs directly.  Cheapest; but AWS rate-limits your CW reads, so not scalable nor reliable.
Lambda -> Cloudwatch. As needed, export Cloudwatch logs to S3. Then read the S3 content and delete it. Cheap, but log export may take up to 12 hours to complete, so not real-time.
Lambda -> Cloudwatch subscription -> Firehose -> S3.  Costs incurred: Cloudwatch storage, Firehose that writes to S3, (Firehose to uncompress logs?), S3 storage.
Lambda -> triggers SNS directly from the code -> SNS runs a Lambda that logs to a Dynamo DB -> Dynamo DB.  Costs incurred: SNS, Lambda, Dynamo DB.

etc.
